# SSH keychain fails to save passphrase when connecting to remote host via SSH as root in macOS

Tags: linux, macos, mac, ssh, keychain

When using SSH to connect between two mac machines **as a standard user** passwordless connection works ok on both macs.

But each time when doing the same **as root** it asks me to enter the passphrase. I got `PermitRootLogin without-password` in my `/etc/sshd-config`

**What's wrong wish my root? Any ideas why does this happen.**

Then:
I've tried to add my passphrase to keychain using this method:

```
$eval "$(ssh-agent)"
$ssh client@macpro.local && ssh-add -K
```

The keychain window appears but for some reason it doesn’t allow to type in it so I just close it. And after I close it terminal prompts me to enter a passphrase. And after I did I get a connection. So I typed

```
$ exit
```

and got this:

```
Could not create keychain item
Identity added: /var/root/.ssh/id_rsa (/var/root/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

So it's a keychain problem I believe (or is it supposed to work this way for any reason?)
Funny thing that after this I actually don't need to enter the passphrase anymore... until I stop ssh-agent :(((((

I tried this on two macs and get absolutely the same result

**Could anyone tell me why keychain [fails|doesn't allow] to save passphrase when sshing as root while it works fine when doing ssh as standard user?**

Comment: Is root enabled on the local Mac? It's not by default.

Comment: Sorry could you explain what you mean more detailed?

Comment: Mac isn't like nix, it doesn't have the root account enabled by default, for security, as almost no process on a Mac ever needs root access. See http://superuser.com/questions/831712/how-can-i-become-root-in-yosemite

Comment: Oh of course it is enabled.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well finally I've found the answer myself and it solved my problem.

So never use the `/usr/local/bin/ssh-add`. Use only default `/usr/bin/ssh-add` which goes with OS X. It works seamlessly with keychain so what I've done is just:

```
$ /usr/bin/ssh-add -k ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Simple. Now the passphrase is permanently stored in my keychain and I don't need to do `ssh-add -k` every time I restart my mac.