# ssh-agent only works as command and not in a script in macOS

Tags: mac, ssh, osx-el-capitan, ssh-agent

I have a Mac with macOS 10.11.6 and had the problem that when I connect through ssh to a server the password (for the private key) was not saved, I had to type it each login. So I found this solution here after this question:

["Mac OS X: keychain fails to save passphrase when connecting to remote host via ssh as root"](https://superuser.com/a/915962/399501) 
and when I do that two commands:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
/usr/bin/ssh-add -k /Volumes/path/to/my/ssh-key
```

on the command line it works. Despite I get a "Could not create keychain item", the password is saved as long as I don't close the Terminal tab where I put those commands.

But when I put these two commands in a shell script and run it as the same user (root) as before, the key is forgotten at the next login. This is the simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
eval `ssh-agent -s`
/usr/bin/ssh-add -k /Volumes/path/to/my/ssh-key
```

I type the password and the SSH session opens, but after exiting it the password is gone, I have to type it again.

What is my error here possibly?

Thank
frank

Answer (score 0):

I added now an alias in my bashrc and with this it works without problem :)

```
alias da='eval `ssh-agent -s` && /usr/bin/ssh-add -K /Volumes/TC20GB/dickies/root/dickies.ssh'
```